# imessage going to receivers messanger or computer, not their phone

Tags: iphone, messages, text

A couple of months ago my friend told me the text messages from my iPhone were going sometimes to her messenger and sometimes to her phone.  I thought perhaps it was a technical issue on her part and dismissed it.  But a similar issue is happening with a client also.  When I send her text messages, they are going to her computer and not her phone.  I video call her to do virtual piano lessons with her two girls on her computer, but we've never had this issue until recently.

Does anyone know if this is a setting on my side or theirs?  And if it is on my end how I would fix this?

Comment: Do you have their email in their contact? Possibly you’re sending it to their email and for some reason they aren’t set up to receive iMessage via that email on their phone but they are on their computer.

Comment: I do have both of their emails added to their contact info, but it is not going to their email.  Both of them have Samsung phones and an Apple iPad I found out today.  The messages are going to the “messages” app on their iPad.